# unable to get some client computer name, visiting my intranet portal in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am unable to get some client computer name not all visiting my intranet site. Any one can help me on this please?

```
public string GetComputerName(string clientIP)
{
    try
    {
        var hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(clientIP);
        return hostEntry.HostName;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

//call GetComputerName function

string computerName = GetComputerName(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress)

Comment: What's happening? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i am not getting any error because of try and catch.but for some users not all, i am not able to get computer name.

Comment: Catching errors doesn't mean they don't occur, it just means you handle them

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on your `return string.Empty` line, then hover over `ex`, what is the error?

Comment: error: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found